# Writing the batch file to enable the wifi in device and connect the adb over wifi

Tags: windows, batch-file, adb, wifi, android-wifi

Here is what I am trying:

```
adb shell wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -Dnl80211 -B -c /etc/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
adb shell wpa_cli -iwlan0 remove_network 0
adb shell wpa_cli -iwlan0 add_network 0
adb shell wpa_cli -iwlan0 set_network 0 ssid '"ACT***"'    //Network name
```

It ALWAYS fails at set_network.
**Error:**

> > adb shell wpa_cli -iwlan0 set_network 0 ssid 'ACT***' FAIL

But if I do below manually it works.

```
adb shell  //enter into shell 
wpa_cli -iwlan0 set_network 0 ssid '"ACT***"'
```

I have tried removing the quotes also didn't help.

Comment: _"It ALWAYS fails at set_network"_ ok, with what error?

Comment: @Gerhard error is > adb shell wpa_cli -iwlan0 set_network 0 ssid 'ACT***'
FAIL
No more information